# Can someone explain the ambiguity in the following sentence? " We decided on the boat."

Tags: prepositions, particles

In one interpretation, *on the boat* is a prepositional phrase telling the location of the decision.

Under the other, *decided on* is a two-part verb with the meaning "chose".

But there is no interpretation in which *on* is a particle. Can you demonstrate that it isn't a particle?

Comment: So, are you looking for differences based on just "on" and "the" in your sample sentence?

Comment: The sentence is just ambiguos, what are you looking for?

Comment: Josh61's comment-answer addresses your title question (which you answer yourself). Lawrence's answer addresses the fact that you need to define which sense of 'particle' you have in mind before you ask the question (and you need to spell it out).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can demonstrate that it isn't a particle.  It doesn't undergo particle shift:

> 1a. We decided **on** the boat.
>   1b. *We decided the boat **on**.

Example 1b is ungrammatical.  Compare the verb-particle idiom ("phrasal verb") *turn on*:

> 2a. I turned **on** the light.
>   2b. I turned the light **on**.

In this verb-particle idiom, the particle *on* can appear after the object, as long as the object isn't an unstressed personal pronoun and isn't extremely long.

This doesn't apply to *decide on*, so we should consider it a verb-preposition idiom.  This is a more precise term than the one you've chosen, "two-part verb", which seems like it could refer to either kind of idiom.

The ambiguity, then, is not syntactic; *decide on* is a verb followed by a preposition regardless of interpretation.  Rather, it's a question of whether *decide on* is taken with its idiomatic meaning, or whether *decide* and *on* are interpreted compositionally.

Comment: Actually, if making a decision somehow causes the boat to light up then 1b is correct.

Answer (score 0):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_particle):

> In grammar the term particle has two different meanings.

Traditional meaning:

> A particle is a part of speech which cannot be inflected, that is it can be neither declined nor conjugated. Particles are the adverb, the preposition, the conjunction and the interjection (a word that has emotion).

Modern meaning:

> In modern grammar, a particle is a function word that must be associated with another word or phrase to impart meaning, i.e., does not have its own lexical definition.

In the traditional meaning of *particle*, *on* is a particle. In the modern meaning, based on your argument, *on* is a particle as part of *on the boat* or *decided on*.

In both cases, *on* would be considered a particle, so the premise that it *isn't* is unsound.